# (Romans 8:38-39) Recipients are believers feeling guilty about sins Vs (Isaiah 59:1-3) Recipients are God's people who willingly sin

Tags: romans, isaiah, hebrew-bible, new-testament, sin

I'm trying compare and contrast Romans 8:38-39 to Isaiah 59:1-3 when it comes to what could separate us from God and/or Love of God.
Please Correct me if my following evaluation/assessment is Wrong.

Let's keep Romans 8 and Isaiah 59 within their separate contexts.

The recipients of Romans 8 whom Paul is addressing are believers (Christians in NT) who ,even though sincere Christians, may have given into the temptation of sin (regardless of whether the sin occurred before or after their acceptance or Jesus Christ), and are feeling guilty and/or unsure of their salvation in Jesus Christ.  Furthermore, the recipients of Romans 8 are told that their feelings of guilt can Stop because they have placed their sins before Jesus Christ which is repentance. Thus, their acceptance of Jesus Christ's salvation puts an End to any sort/kind/form of separation from The Love of God.

The recipients of Isaiah 59:1-3 whom Isaiah is addressing are apathetic/uncaring people of God (Israelites of OT) who willingly sin and ignore God and/or merely paid lip service to God, and therefore go about sinning intentionally, purposely and/or  deliberately.  Moreover, the recipients of Isaiah 59:1-3 are being told their willful, intentional, etc., disobedience and apathy towards God will make God hide His face from them so that God does Not hear them. Thus, their intentional, willful sinfulness separates them from God.

Is the aforementioned evaluation/assessment correct?

> Romans 8 (NASB)
>
> 1 Therefore there is now no condemnation for those who
> are in Christ Jesus. 2 For the law of the Spirit of life [a]in Christ
> Jesus has set you free from the law of sin and of death. 3 For what
> the Law could not do, [b]weak as it was through the flesh, God did:
> sending His own Son in the likeness of [c]sinful flesh and as an
> offering for sin, He condemned sin in the flesh, 4 so that the
> requirement of the Law might be fulfilled in us, who do not walk
> according to the flesh but according to the Spirit.
> .............................................................................................
> ..............................................................................................**35
> Who will separate us from the love of [m]Christ?** Will tribulation, or
> distress, or persecution, or famine, or nakedness, or peril, or sword?
> 36 Just as it is written,
>
> “For Your sake we are being put to death all day long; We were
> considered as sheep to be slaughtered.”
>
> 37 But in all these things we overwhelmingly conquer through Him who
> loved us. **38 For I am convinced that neither death, nor life, nor
> angels, nor principalities, nor things present, nor things to come,
> nor powers, 39 nor height, nor depth, nor any other created thing,
> will be able to separate us from the love of God**, which is in Christ
> Jesus our Lord.

> Isaiah 59:1-3 (NASB)
>
> 59 Behold, the Lord’s hand is not so short That it
> cannot save; Nor is His ear so dull That it cannot hear. **2 But your
> iniquities have made a separation between you and your God, And your
> sins have hidden His [a]face from you so that He does not hear.** 3 For
> your hands are defiled with blood And your fingers with iniquity; Your
> lips have spoken falsehood, Your tongue mutters wickedness.

Is the aforementioned evaluation/assessment correct?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the assessment.

The stating of the failure of law because it is 'weak through the flesh' emphasizes the weakness of the flesh and its prone-ness to fail.

The stating of 'condemned sin in the flesh' and the stating of 'walking in the Spirit, not in the flesh' all agree with your assessment.

It is an exhortation to those who admit their failure under law, whenever that failure occurred, whether before or after conversion.

This agrees with John the apostle :

> My little children, these things write I unto you, that ye sin not. And if any man sin, we have an advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous: [1 John 2:1 KJV]

Those spoken to by the prophet Isaiah are a hardened people who are sinning against the weak, against the needy and are sinning in a violent way against their fellow men - another thing altogether from a penitent person who has failed in a personal way in their private walk with the Lord.

Both Paul's and John's exhortations are to persons in faith, those who have a relationship with the Father, through Jesus Christ his Son ; and who are yet in the body, yet subject to frailty. Whose personal and spiritual walk may be disturbed by their own faults in the flesh, private matters - not outrageous sins against or involving other people.

It is altogether another thing when we see prophets raised up to admonish the natural children of Israel regarding outright idolatry, the oppression of widows and orphans, the ill-treatment of strangers, and the robbing of the poor to give to the rich. As often happened, and as is often recorded in scripture.